# Compare Multiple JSON Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have 3 arrays as displayed below. I have no control over the arrays.

```
groups_array = [ {
    "group" : "Mobile Test Region",
    "id" : "251"
}, {
    "group" : "Mobile Demo Region",
    "id" : "252"
} ]
locations_array = [ {
    "location" : "M Testing",
    "id" : "1376"
}, {
    "location" : "Trade Show Machine",
    "id" : "1403"
}, {
    "location" : "M Trailer",
    "id" : "1471"
}, {
    "location" : "Test Los Angeles",
    "id" : "1475"
} ]
pairs_array = [ {
    "location_id" : "1376",
    "group_id" : "251"
}, {
    "location_id" : "1475",
    "group_id" : "251"
}, {
    "location_id" : "1403",
    "group_id" : "252"
}, {
    "location_id" : "1471",
    "group_id" : "252"
} ]
```

Here is the code I used to loop through the pairs_array and retrieve the location_id's that correspond with the group id. Ti.API.info(pairs_array[s].location_id);  outputs 2 location ID's based on the groupid given using e.rowData.groupid.

```
for (var s = 0; s < pairs_array.length; s++) {
    if (e.rowData.groupid === pairs_array[s].group_id) {
        Ti.API.info(pairs_array[s].location_id); 
    }
}
```

I am trying to compare the strings and retrieve the location names using the location_id's ive gotten from the IF statement. Should I just push the results into an array and loop through the location_array and the results and compare? If so, I'd like to see a good code snippet for that since the few times I tried I was not getting the expected output.

Comment: Interesting. What is your question?

Comment: what is your question? what have you tried so far? (have you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)?)

Comment: Please do read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Stating that you're "having problems" doesn't help us *solve* your problem.

Comment: Write the rest of your code. Tell us what results are output, and what you expect instead. Use the terms "expected results" and "actual results". Use a site like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) to write a quick demo of your problem, one that can show people who are trying to help you exactly what you are experiencing.

Comment: Also, if you have control over the structure of those arrays, consider turning them into object hashes with the "id" parameter as the key, if you want to do multidimensional lookups.

Comment: Question has been updated with hopefully what is a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var s = 0; s < pairs_array.length; s++) {
    if (e.rowData.groupid === pairs_array[s].group_id) {
        Ti.API.info(pairs_array[s].location_id); 

        // find location name
        for(var t = 0; t < locations_array.length; t++)
        {
            if(locations_array[t].id == pairs_array[s].location_id)
            {
                location_name = locations_array[t].location;                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. I guess I was concerned about inheritance of the variable when doing multiple for/if statements. I'm still a noob. Thanks for baring with me.

Comment: Hi Chris. Ideally as @zetlen said 'if you have control over the structure of those arrays, consider turning them into object hashes with the "id" parameter as the key'